# How to break out of for loop in protractor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

This is my code -

```
formElements[0].findElements(by.repeater(repeater)).then(function(items){
            console.log(i, '>>>>>>>>>.No of items in the list --- '+items.length);
            (function(items){
                for(var x1=0; x1<itemsToBeSelected.length; x1++){
                    console.log(i, '>>>>>>.Looking for item --- '+itemsToBeSelected[x1]);
                    skip = false;
                    (function(items, x1){
                        for(var x2=0; x2<items.length; x2++){
                            (function(items, x2){
                                items[x2].getText().then(function(itemName){
                                   console.log(i, '>>>>..Verifying '+itemsToBeSelected[x1]+' with '+itemName);
                                   if(itemName == itemsToBeSelected[x1]){
                                       console.log(i, '>>>>>.Selecting the item --- '+itemName);
                                       items[x2].findElement(by.css('.regular-checkbox')).click();

                                   }
                                });
                            }(items, x2));
                        }
                    }(items, x1));
                }
            }(items));
        });
```

I want to break out of inner for loop when the condition itemName == itemsToBeSelected[x1] is satisfied. Tried using flag, return statements, but unable to break out from the loop.

Please suggest corrections in the code.

Comment: have you tried simply return;?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ptor.element.all(by.repeater(repeater)).then(function(products){
           console.log(i, '>>>>>>>>>.Products length --- '+products.length);
           async.each(products, verifyName, function(err){
               console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>err value --- '+err);
               expect(err).toBe(true);
               if(err){
                   console.log(i, '>>>>>>>>.Element is present');
               }else{
                   console.log(i, '>>>>>>>>.Element is not present');
               }
           });
            function verifyName(product, callback){
                console.log(i, '>>>>>>>>.Inside function verifyName');
                product.getText().then(function(name){
                    console.log('>>>>>>>>>>Looking for product --- '+name);
                    if(name==entityName){
                        console.log(i, '>>>>>>>>Verified the name - '+name);
                        callback(true);
                    }
                });
            }
    });
```

We can achieve the same results with the help of async.each module as well. For e.g. I've posted a code in which i'm trying to find a single value.

So in relation to my question, we can click or perform any action on the element before setting callback(true). Say for e.g. here we could do - product.click();

Comment: I am getting ReferenceError: `async is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind what I said before the edit, you could use [caolan's async module](https://github.com/caolan/async#detectarr-iterator-callback) to iterate over your array, with the detect or detectSeries function.

It should look something like this :

```
formElements[0].findElements(by.repeater(repeater)).then(function(items) {
  console.log(i, '>>>>>>>>>.No of items in the list --- ' + items.length);
  itemsToBeSelected.forEach(function(itemToBeSelected) {
    async.detect(items, function(item, next) {
      item.getText().then(function(itemName) {
        // This function will be called on each item in items, until next(true) is called
        console.log('Verifying ' + itemToBeSelected + ' with ' + itemName);
        // Here you call the callback with the truth value :
        return next(itemName === itemToBeSelected);
      });
    }, function(item) {
      // This function is called with the first item that resulted in a true
      // callback value.
      console.log('Selecting the item --- ' + item);
      item.findElement(by.css('.regular-checkbox')).click();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had tried this already. And this doesn't work. It goes into the if condition, it sets the breaker = true. But after it exits function(items, x2), breaker's value becomes false. Hence not able to break out of the loop.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't notice the asynchronous then().

Comment: can you please post an example code for my scenario, since I'm not able to understand this module clearly?