# How to stop executing a loop (say if loop once it finds a match) in Protractor for AngularJS applications?

Tags: angularjs, automation, protractor

I am writing test cases using protractor for AngularJS Application. I want to stop an if loop once it finds the value. Is there any equivalent function available that I can use to stop executing the loop further in Protractor, like we have break in C.

Answer (score 2):

[`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) is a javascript instruction:

```
function testBreak(x) {
   var i = 0;
   while (i < 6) {
      if (i == 3) {
         break;
      }
      i += 1;
   }
   return i * x;
}
```

A complete reference of the language is available on the [mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) with a list of all [the statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

---

Brendan Eich wrote:

> JavaScript borrows most of its syntax from Java, but also inherits
>   from Awk and Perl, with some indirect influence from Self in its
>   object prototype system.

NB: This question is neither specific to protractor, nor angular.js nor to automation.

Comment: My question is not related to JavaScript. Question is how to break out of for OR if loop in protractor. Java Script break statement doesn't work.

Comment: I think you should provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) because none of us understand your question.

Comment: Okay. So I have if statement with a condition. I want to come out of if loop once the condition is met. As of now my if loop is executing for every value. So basically I want to break my If loop once condition is met. Say for example, if(item1 == item2){ statment, break;}

Comment: I am sorry but i still don't understand. What is a `if loop` for you ?  My `testBreak` example shows how to leave a `while` loop when a condition is met (`if (i == 3)`). I think you should be more specific in your question, you will get a better help sonner. Moreover i am the only one notified of your comments on my answer.

Comment: exactly..I want to leave a if loop when condition is met. Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553987/how-to-break-out-of-for-loop-in-protractor.

Answer (score 0):

you also have the break statement in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is break/continue in javascript:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is my code and i want break after if statement because text has been match i dont want to again go to else block

```
  for (i = 0; i <row.length; i++)  
       {

    var obj_dn_ocnele=obj_dn_ocndrpdown_elements.get(i).getText().then(function(text) {
      var test_var1 = text.trim();
      console.log(test_var1);
      outer:{
      if (test_var1 == var_ocn_id)
       {
        log.info(var_ocn_id +"ocn exist");
        break outer; 
       }

      else
      {
        log.error(var_ocn_id +"ocn not exist");
         break outer;
      }

      }

      });


    }
```